# $k = 1,2,...$, why the roots of $\cos (k \arccos(x))$ are $x_i=\cos \frac{\pi (2i-1)}{2k},i=1,...,k$

Tags: calculus

For any $k = 1,2,...$, why the roots of $\cos (k \arccos(x)) = 0$ are $x_i=\cos \frac{\pi (2i-1)}{2k},i=1,...,k$?

Thanks to help by Stefan4024, above means $\arccos(x_i)=\frac {i\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}}{k},i=1,2,...$, then it means $x_i=\cos(\frac {i\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}}{k}),i=1,2,...$. Now I need help why there are at most $k$ such solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\arccos(x) = y \iff \cos(y) = x$$

---

For the second part note that $\cos(x) = 0 \iff x=n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$, hence we have: $k \arccos(x) = \frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2} \iff \arccos(x) = \frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2k} \iff x = \cos\left(\frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2k}\right)$

Now note : $$\cos\left(\frac{(2(n+k)+ 1)\pi}{2k}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2k}\right)$$

So hence we can take $n$ modulo $k$ and get all the unique solutions. Hence as there are $k$ remainders modulo $k$ there are $k$ unique solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I go one step further. Now I am puzzled why there are at most $k$ solutions?

Comment: @user432594 I edit my answer. Hope it gives you what you want